# Plot doesn't show up when I try to insert a vertical line

Tags: python, matplotlib

The title speaks for itself. I have a [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIXrY.png) that was generated from the code below.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True,  figsize =(15,15))
ax1.plot(Time_range, pressure)
ax1.set_ylabel('Pressure (nPa)')
nbins = len(ax1.get_xticklabels())
ax2.plot(Time_range, SymH)
ax2.set_ylabel('SymH')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
ax3.plot(Time_range, AE_INDEX)
ax3.set_ylabel('AE_INDEX')
ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
ax3.set_xlabel('Time HH:MM')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

I then tried to draw a vertical line through the last subplot, but for some reason [this was my result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DTiq.png)

The only difference was the `axvline` that I added almost at the end.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True,  figsize =(15,15))
ax1.plot(Time_range, pressure)
ax1.set_ylabel('Pressure (nPa)')
nbins = len(ax1.get_xticklabels())
ax2.plot(Time_range, SymH)
ax2.set_ylabel('SymH')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
ax3.plot(Time_range, AE_INDEX)
ax3.set_ylabel('AE_INDEX')
ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
ax3.set_xlabel('Time HH:MM')
ax3.axvline(x = event_index, color = 'r')

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Is the `axvline` doing something else that i'm not aware of?

By the way, the `pressure`, `SymH` and `AE_INDEX` data were from a file that I read in.

Comment: Obviously `event_index` lies far outside the range given by `Time_range`. And that's already all one can tell from the code you share: Introducing an unknown variable in the code changes it's outcome, not very surprising I'd say.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll try to see if the event_index falls within range. Also sorry for my questioning format.